# Google workspace - Hide alias

Tags: email, gmail, alias, google-workspace

I can't find the setting that hides an alias of an email address on Google Workspace.

I created an alias to redirect emails from old.employee@mydomain.com to new.employee@mydomain.com by following this doc: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6304345?hl=en

By following this process, all aliases are visible on the new.employee@mydomain.com profile in Google contacts under Contact Information. I really want to hide secondary email addresses attached to new.employee@mydomain.com
Exactly like a postfix configuration for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the "Directory settings" Like this:

[image]

the path is: **Directory** > **Directory settings** > **Sharing settings**
Just make sure to click on the section "Contact sharing" so you can have access to those additional option :)

#### References:

- [Google Workspace - Directory settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60218)